# Export csv file to seed postgres table in different environments

Tags: postgresql, csv, database-migration

I want to export a .csv file to seed a table via postgres. I am aware of the `copy` command and it works fine when the .csv file is a local path.

`COPY table_name FROM '/path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER`

Where can I store the .csv file in different environments that aren't local? For example, when I run the seed migration in production, where exactly is it going to get the .csv file to seed the tables in prod?

Answer (score 0):

You have options, but they all boil down to [copying from `stdin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

You can pipe the CSV into the `psql` client.

```
cat dump.csv | psql -c 'COPY table_name FROM '/path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER'
```

Or you can use `\copy ... from stdin` inside [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Or you can use the [`pg_restore` tool](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) which basically does the same thing, but is nicer to use, and has lots of options.